# Chat search fails to load autocomplete list for users more than once

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

As a heavy user of chat search, I've repeatedly run into a bug in the chat search page affecting the autocomplete list for the username ("when said by...") box:

[image: User autocomplete box in chat search]

If I type part of a username quickly, the list shows up properly as shown above, but if I type more characters in the username box to refine the list of results, it gets stuck and the loading throbber in the box never disappears. I can't get any more autocomplete results from the box until I refresh the page. Firefox returns the following error in the developer console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More] jquery.min.js:4:16639
    n.parseJSON https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:16639
    formatResult https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/js/master.js:1:19300
    f https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/js/master.js:2:3101
    d https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/js/master.js:2:2531
    o https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/js/master.js:2:1506
```

In Microsoft Edge, I get a similar error in `jquery.min.js`, line 3 column 16631:

```
SCRIPT5655: JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:1
```

I do not have Chrome available for testing but I'd suppose it would fail similarly.

Can someone look into this?

Comment: Funny, I could've sworn this came up before with some other autocomplete field in chat, but can't find it now.

Comment: ...and voting to close my own question.